# How to return mongoDB results from a class in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a class that handles all of my database operations for an API that I'm working on. As of right now, this is what my selection function looks like:

```
def select_all_images(self, connection):
    return connection.landmark_id_ii.landmark_image.find({})
    # col = connection.landmark_id_ii.landmark_image
    # cur = col.find()

    # return cur

    # for doc in cur:
    #     print(doc)

def select_image_by_id(self, connection, _id):
    return connection.landmark_id_ii.landmark_image.find({"_id": ObjectId(_id)})
    # return connection.landmark_id_ii.landmark_image.find()[2]
```

The functions themselves actually do work, because running a count on the results object that comes back returns that there are 11 items in the list, but I cannot get the results to be anything other than `<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x10c7dce80>` or `None`. Below is how I'm calling the functions:

```
images = db_helper.select_all_images(connection)
```

or

```
image = db_helper.select_image_by_id(connection, '5e95c9ca6cd6c732d8fc259f')
```

Please let me know if you want me to provide additional information.

Answer (score 0):

try to return

```
return list(images)
```

as the cursor structure should be a list of dictionaries imho.

As for the search for 'id' I assume you expect one result. Hence I'd suggest you use MongoDBs find_one like this

```
item = self.item_col.find_one({"_id": itemid})
```

You can return the result as it will be a dictionary